# How do I move data of 1list into 2nd list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

List1: ObservationVersion2
List2: ObservationVersion3

How do I move data(All field/columns) of List1 into List2. Problem is There are few extra columns in List2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any migration tool like sharegate, Metalogix or even free version of Microsoft migration tool...or you can write some workflow or MS Flow or at last by PowerShell coding.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I am using Microsoft Migration took, getting error while adding sharepoint list.

Comment: I have added error Picture down below

Comment: Cannot get user name from SharePoint OnPrem Server

Comment: Please mention you are working on which version of SharePoint? And what is the migration tool you are using?

Comment: If you are using sharegate or Metalogix... you can configure the missing user with the migration user account or any account... so that we will not get any error during migration with respect to missing user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Migration tool part, were the two lists in the same site collection?  Or same farm? Where are they located? What version of SharePoint are you using? The SharePoint Migration tool is used for migrating contents in a SP on-premise farm to SharePoint Online.

If you are handling two SharePoint Lists in the same tenant. Both MS flows or PowerShell scripts will help you do the work.For using CSOM PowerShell, have a check on this [Copy List Items From One SharePoint List To Another Using CSOM PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copy-list-items-from-one-sharepoint-list-to-another-using-csom-powershell/)

For the example of MS flow, you can check this:
[Copy data between two SharePoint lists (or any two data sources) efficiently](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/copying-using-filtering/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using console app in c#. You can read data from first list one by one and then map into new list.